# Is this the correct way to detect ray-sphere intersection?

Tags: java, android, raycasting, intersection

I have this java function that should return a true or false for any sphere passed to it if they intersect. However it seems to end being true a lot of the time when it shouldn't and false sometimes when it should be true.

It is possible however that i am passing incorrect data to the function. This was done with jPCT so the object SimpleVector is a vector with 3 variables.

```
public Boolean sphereIntersect(SimpleVector rayOrigin,SimpleVector rayDirection, SimpleVector sphereOrigin, float sphereRadius )
{
        SimpleVector Q = new SimpleVector(sphereOrigin);
        Q.sub(rayOrigin);

          float c = sphereOrigin.length();
          float v = Q.calcDot(rayDirection);
          float d = sphereRadius*sphereRadius - (c*c - v*v);

          if (d < 0.0){
              System.out.println("False");
          return false;
          }
          System.out.println("True");
          return true;  

}
```

Comment: you'll want to get the [distance from point to a line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
float c = sphereOrigin.length();
```

with

```
float c = Q.length();
```

Comment: Yup, that was it, I made a change and forgot it required subsequent changes.

Comment: Hey, I found this question very useful but I cannot seem to be able to properly use OP's function: 
"sphereIntersect(a, b.calcSub(a); new SimpleVector(0, 0, 0), MY_RADIUS);"
Any pointers?

Comment: I don't understand. Do you have a problem with OPs code or with my fix?